# NET::HTTP on rails anyway to increase timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, net-http

I have making a NET:HTTP call to a third party payment API using form_post method from NET:HTTP using rails.

```
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, payment_details)
logger.info "RESPONSE: #{res}"
descrypted_res = JSON.parse(res.body)
logger.info "RESPONSE: #{descrypted_res}"
```

sometimes, I got the response back saying HTTPOK, sometimes i dont get anything at all. I am suspecting the payment server did not respond to my request in time and the connection is terminated. My question is, is there any way to increase the post_form timeout duration? 
I want to increase it to 60 seconds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the ruby method:
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-post_form

like this:

```
def _post_form(url, params)
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
  req.form_data = params
  req.basic_auth url.user, url.password if url.user
  Net::HTTP.start(
    url.hostname,
    url.port,
    use_ssl: url.scheme == 'https',
    read_timeout: 600
  ) do |http|
    http.request(req)
  end
end
```